# Error code: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Tags: python, string, floating-point

Here is my code, but I keep getting an error

```
weight_lbs = input("what is your weight in lbs? ")
weight_kg = int(weight_lbs) * 0.45
print("your weight is " + weight_kg)
```

Comment: Your variable weight_kg is an integer while "your weight is" is a string. Python cannot combine/concatenate a string and an integer, so you much first convert the integer to a string.

Comment: Its fairly trivial in this case, but the python traceback that shows the error should be posted along with the code. Its all part of the debugging process.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a formatted string:

```
print(f"your weight is {weight_kg}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't join a float and a string (`weight_kg`) together.

Change:

```
print("your weight is " + weight_kg)
```

To:

```
print("your weight is " + str(weight_kg))
```

Comment: This is exactly what @OsadhiVirochanaJayasingheSi answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62476667/13552470

Answer (score 2):

You can use a formatted string:

```
print(f"your weight is {weight_kg}")
```

The reason you don't have to convert the variable with a formatted string 
is because the variables in the string are evaluated during runtime.

Comment: I think this method is relatively better than the other methods of converting to integer type to a string. It's newer and very concise and useful, although the other approaches are still very valid and correct.

Answer (score 2):

you can't add float to string because they have different types try this solution :

```
print("your weight is {}".format(weight_kg))
```

or

```
print(f"your weight is {weight_kg}")
```

or

```
print("your weight is ",weight_kg)
```

or

```
print("your weight is "+str(weight_kg))
```

Comment: Thank you. As a beginner, your answers made me realize that there are different ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`print("your weight is " + weight_kg)`

to

`print("your weight is " + str(weight_kg))`.

You can't add Float to String.

Answer (score 1):

```
weight_lbs = input("what is your weight in lbs? ")
```

`input()` returns a string. Therefore, `weight_lbs` is a string.

```
weight_kg = int(weight_lbs) * 0.45
```

`weight_kg` returns a float.

In your print statement, you are trying to concatenate string and float, which python does not allow.

So please convert `weight_kg` to string:

```
print("your weight is " + str(weight_kg))
```

And this should work!